# subscription to behaviour subject don't work on all components

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, subscription, behaviorsubject

I my global service I instiante a behaviourSubject variable

**dataWorkFlowService**:

```
export class CallWorkflowService {
  url = 'http://localhost:3000/';
  selectedNode : BehaviorSubject<Node> = new BehaviorSubject(new Node(''))
  dataflow : BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getDataflow() {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
  updateNode(node :Node) {
    this.selectedNode.next(node);
  }
}
```

In my component **ReteComponent** I set behaviourSubject value using

`this.dataFlowService.selectedNode.next(node);`

Im my second component I subscribe to the BehaviourSubject

```
export class ComponentsMenuComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private callWorkflowService:CallWorkflowService) { }
selectedNode:Node = new Node('');
dataFlow:any;
nxtElements:String[]=[]

ngOnInit() {


    this.callWorkflowService.dataflow.subscribe(data=> {
      this.dataFlow=data
    })
    this.callWorkflowService.selectedNode.subscribe( (node) => {
      this.selectedNode=node; <=== ###### Subscription is not triggered
      if(this.dataFlow) {
        this.nxtElements=this.dataFlow[node.name].next;
      }

    })
  }
```

When I trigger new value to `selectedNode` my subscription does not work

But in another component it's working well

```
export class AppComponent {
  opened:boolean=false;
  events: string[] = [];
  constructor(private callWorkflowService:CallWorkflowService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.callWorkflowService.selectedNode.pipe(
      skip(1)
    )
    .subscribe( (node) => {
      this.opened=true; <== subscription is working
    })
  }
}
```

I have noticed in that in **ComponentsMenuComponent** when I change it to

```
export class ComponentsMenuComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private callWorkflowService:CallWorkflowService) { }
selectedNode:Node = new Node('');
dataFlow:any;
nxtElements:String[]=[]

ngOnInit() {
     this.callWorkflowService.getDataflow().subscribe(data=> {
       this.dataFlow=data;
     }) ####CHANGE HERE ### <== using `getDataFlow` method which is not observable
    this.callWorkflowService.selectedNode.subscribe( (node) => {
      this.selectedNode=node; ### <=== subscription is triggered
      if(this.dataFlow) {
        this.nxtElements=this.dataFlow[node.name].next;
      }

    })
  }
```

the selectNode subscription is working.

**Update** 
I have tried to change how I proceed

In my service I added a method that return last value

```
updateDataFlow() {
  return this.dataflow.getValue();
}
```

In **ComponentsMenuComponent**

```
this.callWorkflowService.node.subscribe( (node) => {
  this.dataFlow = this.callWorkflowService.updateDataFlow();
  this.selectedNode=node;
  if(this.dataFlow) {
    this.nxtElements=this.dataFlow[node.name].next;
  }

})
```

Here again subscription is not working..

I have tried to comment the line

`this.dataFlow = this.callWorkflowService.updateDataFlow();`

And here surprise.. subscription works.

I don't know why it don't subscribe when I uncomment the line that I have mentioned

Comment: Add stackblitz please.

Answer (score 0):

You must be providing your CallWorkflowService incorrectly and getting a different instance of the service in different components. If one component is working and another is not then I would guess that they are not both subscribed to the same behavior subject.

How are you providing the service? Is it provided in a module, component or are you using provided in?